# Use of `-M` switch in git?

Tags: git, github

When I created a repository in github, following commands were shown to add existing local repository to remote.

I assume `-M` switch is to merge the local branch with remote.

But there is no reference of this switch in git manuals I searched. For eg [this manual.](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/git.1.html)

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/test/test.git
git branch -M main
git push -u origin main
```

Is this some special aliasing?

Comment: See http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt--M

Comment: hmm, why should be this missing from ubuntu man page as well.

Comment: Because it is part of `git branch` and not just `git`. See [the manual for `git branch`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/git-branch.1.html).

Comment: https://www.biteinteractive.com/of-git-and-github-master-and-main/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github changed the default branch name from master to main in 2020. `git branch -M main` changes your local branch name to main. If you try to push by running `git push -u origin main` without renaming your branch first, it will probably give you an error.

To permanently change your git default branch name, you can run this command.

```
git config --global init.defaultBranch main
```

You might have to restart your terminal for it to take affect. After you have done this, all new local repos should be initialized with the default branch name being main, and you won't have to change your local branch name before pushing.

Comment: git config --global init.defaultBranch main. Does this have any side effects, other than changing the branch name?

Comment: No, it does not. It just adds a line of code to your .gitconfig file telling git to set the default branch name to main, nothing else. You will be able to see the changes if you open up your .gitconfig file, should be in your home directory.

Comment: Here's some documentation.
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup

Comment: Note that `init.defaultBranch` is new; older versions of Git let you *set* it, but this has no effect until you upgrade your Git to version 2.30 or later.